# Remove ASCII or Unicode characters from encrypted data

Tags: c#, encryption, unicode, ascii

I'm trying to get an encrypted code stored in a MySQL database using C#. Sometimes the code is fine but sometimes I get some ASCII and Unicode characters at the end of the decrypted code.

I understand, because of the encryption/decryption process, you get some extra characters; the problem is that those characters are not consistent (is not like I always get a bunch of \0 at the end).

```
codeA\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
codeB\u0010\u0010\u0010\u0010\u0010\u0010\u0010\u0010\u0010
codeC\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b
codeD\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0003
```

I get different ending characters and to be honest it would be difficult to add a "Replace" method for every character that happens to appear.

Is there a way to remove those "special" characters at the end? Or maybe am I just storing/reading the code wrong?

I write the process for PHP (web page utf-8, the writer of the code) and C# (console app, the reader of the code)

**PHP**

```
// Get $code from html form in utf-8

$code = $_POST['code'];
$encrypted_code = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($code, 'aes-256-ecb', 'keykeykeykeykeykeykeykey', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA)));

// Store $encrypted_code into database
```

**C#**

```
// Read encrypted_code from database using MySqlConnection

Aes aes = Aes.Create();
aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("keykeykeykeykeykeykeykey");
aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
aes.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
string code = null;
using (aes)
{
            byte[] encrypted_code = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted_code);
            using (var encrypted_stream = new MemoryStream(encrypted_code))
            using (var decrypter_stream = new CryptoStream(encrypted_stream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            using (var decrypted_stream = new StreamReader(decrypter_stream))
            code = decrypted_stream.ReadLine().
                        Replace("\0", string.Empty).
                        Replace("\b", string.Empty).
                        Replace("\v", string.Empty).
                        Replace("\t", string.Empty).
                        Replace("\u0010", string.Empty).
                        Replace("\u0003", string.Empty).
                        Replace("\u0006", string.Empty);
}

//Use code for whatever
```

Comment: 0x10 is Data Link Escape and 0x03 is End of Text. You may check if source contains those special characters in the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the PHP encryption method you chose adds padding which returns data results like "CodeA\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0". In order to get decrypted data returned without the padding simply change the `PaddingMode` in the C# code to:

`aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;`

---

BTW: 
This code:
`$encrypted_code = openssl_encrypt($code, 'aes-256-ecb', 'keykeykeykeykeykeykeykey');`

produces the same as this code:
`$encrypted_code = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($code, 'aes-256-ecb', 'keykeykeykeykeykeykeykey', OPENSSL_RAW_DATA));`

Comment: It worked, thanks. I also change the PHP as you sugest.